# Desktop does not show file icons even if they are in the desktop folder after 20.04 upgrade

Tags: upgrade, icons

I upgraded 20.04 from 18.04 and Desktop files are there in the folder but not shown in the desktop screen.

Comment: If you have an `Extensions` app, start it and make sure that the desktop-icon extension is enabled.

Comment: `Extensions` or `Tweaks` or https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ will do the trick.

Comment: cannot change desktop icon color, which I need to, gnome shell option appears empty and with a warning icon on tweaks. Can you help me with?

Comment: Explicity try "Extensions" rather than "Tweaks". Install it with `sudo apt install gnome-shell -extension-prefs`, load it searching for  "Extensions" in the application overview, and enable "Desktop Icons" there (or turn off-on again). This is probably a typical "upgrade pain". Upgrades are not always flawless.

Comment: Can you tell me if I can uninstall Tweaks without harm, leaving the system as it was? I am a very non expert user. So as to go on a clean operation with Extensions as you suggest. Thank you !!

Comment: To fix the `Tweaks` gnome shell option you must install the `user-theme` extension and enable it. But if you want a stock appearance then don't bother. No need to uninstall Tweaks... it's a useful tool.